# How to remove matching letters in a string that come after a comma? Python

Tags: python

I am working on a coding challenge that takes user input removes matching letters that come after a comma and scrubs the white space. For the life of me I can’t figure it out.

For example the user inputs:
`Hello World, wea`

Output would be:
`Hllo orld`

Any direction on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated it is driving me crazy.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: better show your code.

Comment: it seems it needs two parts - first has to find comma, second has to remove chars in string after comma.

Comment: It's a coding challenge. You haven't even begun, and you're asking others to solve it for you? I don't think you get the point of the exercise...

Comment: That is not the case at all I tried using a split to separate the text after the comma. Then pull the letters out of a list and assign to a variable and then pass through with a re.sub but not matter what I did I couldn’t get it to work. I typed that while sitting at dinner so I apologize for not showing what I had already tried. But couldn’t get it out of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a simple for loop that iterates across the phrase and places characters that don't appear after the comma into a separate string. Then the separate string is the result once the for loop has finished.

There are tons of different ways of achieving this, this way is fairly easy to understand though.

```
text = "Hello World, wea"
phrase, chars = text.split(",")  # split the text by the comma
chars = chars.strip()            # remove whitespace from second part
output = ""                      # separate string to collect chars
for letter in phrase:
    if letter.lower() not in chars: # check lowercased letters 
       output += letter             
print(output)
```

output

```
Hllo orld
```